# How to use Node.js repl with file as input

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I wish to use a `js` file input as node.js `repl`, as if it was a command line code: 
`node -e '<my code>'`, but with a `<filename>` instead of an inline code.

How can this be done as the file name as an input, without needing to use another file (such as `fs.readFileSync(..)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the REPL's [`.load` command](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_commands_and_special_keys) and Node's `-i` flag.

```
echo ".load test.js" | node -i
```

Outputs:

```
$ echo ".load test.js" | node -i 
Welcome to Node.js v12.8.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> .load test.js
2 + 2;

4
```

Comment: It does not evaluate expressions as REPL does.

Comment: I see, I understand now. Check my updated answer and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: it did work - however, the problem with this solution is that it only evaluates the last statement.